# How to use jEditable module with Computed Field module?

Tags: 7, entities

I've done some computations using [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module like the follows.

**First**

**Second**

**Total**(first+second) (computed field)

I've installed [jEditable inline content editing](https://drupal.org/project/jeditable) module to do inline edit at node display. How to use this module with computed filed. Here is my problem

Lets say I've node like the following

**First** - 35

**Second** - 4

**Total**  - 39

If I change the value of **First** from 35 to 38 (using jEditable field) and save, it's updating the filed, but the value of **total** remains the same. I'm getting correct result when I **refresh** the page. (Ofcourse, I know the reason).  I need to get updated value of total whenever I change the values of first/second. How can I achieve this?

For better understand I've added images

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The jEditable, is based on an ajax request, and it works only for your first field, it's normal what you see there untill you refresh page to see changes...

here some snippets that can help :

1- create a callback menu item :

```
function MYMODULE_menu(){
$items['edit_total/ajax'] = array(
    'title' => t('Edit Total AJAX'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'edit_total_ajax',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
return $items;
}
```

2- create the callback function that will return the new total field :

```
function edit_total_ajax(){
    $data = array();

    if(isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['second'])){
        $first = $_POST['first'];
        $second = $_POST['second'];
        data['total'] = (is_numeric($first) && is_numeric($second)) ? $first + $second : "undefined";
    }
    drupal_json_output($data); // return data as json output, this is the best return for me!
}
```

3- Now you must have a simple jQuery snippet to send the first and the second value :

```
$(function(){
  // you can add here an event handler (on submit for examle)
  jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/edit_total/ajax', // the same that made in hook_menu
       dataType: 'json',
       data: { first: $("YOUR_FIRST_SELECTOR").val(), second: $("YOUR_SECOND_SELECTOR").val()  },
       success: function(data){

                 if(data.total !== 'undefined'){
                        $("YOUR_TOTAL_SELECTOR").text(data.total) // this is will change the text value of total field by the new one !
                    }
                 }
       });
});
```